# bigmemory and rownames/dimnames of matrix

Tags: r, memory-management, matrix, dataframe

I have some standard, clean `csv` file that I make a `.bin` file for with bigmemory.

```
require(bigmemory)
options(bigmemory.allow.dimnames=TRUE)
DR1 <- read.big.matrix("aord_0900_ret_d.csv",type="double",backingfile="DR1.bin",descriptorfile="DR1.desc",has.row.names=TRUE,header=TRUE)
```

Here, `rownames(DR1)` will return the rownames, as will `dimnames(DR1)[[1]]`. Just what I want!!

However, if I exit `RGui.exe` and re-open it, then enter the following:

```
require(bigmemory)
options(bigmemory.allow.dimnames=TRUE)
DR1 <- attach.big.matrix("DR1.desc")
```

`rownames(DR1)` and `dimnames(DR1)[[1]]` will both give me `NULL`. However, `DR1` is perfectly correct apart from this deletion of rownames. Even `colnames(DR1)` works.

---

I want the `rownames(DR1)` to work.

Comment: Looks like an error in the package to me. I'm getting the same when I try this with dummy data. The rownames are not written to the .desc file. Reading in the csv and then assigning DR1 with bigmemory::as.big.matrix from an in memory matrix will write out the rownames though.